# how to convert nested lists into a matrix, filling missing values with 0

Tags: r

I have some tabled values out of a function that gives me a list like:

```
> mylist
[[1]]
0 
3 

[[2]]
0 1 
1 3 

[[3]]
1 2 
4 1
```

According to this nested list, I have observations for label 0, label 1 and label 2, but not all the lists contains all these labels, so and I would like to organize mylist as a matrix like:

```
     0  1  2 
[1]  3  0  0
[2]  1  3  0
[3]  0  4  1
```

my point is to then make a box plot. Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably not the most elegant solution:

```
tmp <- list(c(0,0,0), c(0,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,1,2))
lst <- lapply(tmp, table)

nam <- unique(unlist(lapply(lst, names)))
outRow <- rep(0, length(nam))
names(outRow) <- nam

t(sapply(lst, function(x) {out <- outRow;
   out[names(x)] <- x
   out
}))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are some alternatives:

Some sample data (thanks to Gavin Kelly).

```
tmp <- list(c(0,0,0), c(0,1,1,1), c(1,1,1,1,2))
lst <- lapply(tmp, table)
```

A base R approach. Use `data.frame` on the `table` output, and add an "id" variable that shows us which list item it comes from. Use `do.call(rbind, ...)` to put it together as a long `data.frame`, and `xtabs` to get the output you want.

```
out <- do.call(rbind, lapply(seq_along(lst), function(x) 
  cbind(id = x, data.frame(lst[[x]]))))
out
#   id Var1 Freq
# 1  1    0    3
# 2  2    0    1
# 3  2    1    3
# 4  3    1    4
# 5  3    2    1

xtabs(Freq ~ id + Var1, out)
#    Var1
# id  0 1 2
#   1 3 0 0
#   2 1 3 0
#   3 0 4 1
```

---

This process is even more convenient with the "reshape2" package since `melt` can handle `list`s.

```
library(reshape2)
melt(lst)
#   Var1 value L1
# 1    0     3  1
# 2    0     1  2
# 3    1     3  2
# 4    1     4  3
# 5    2     1  3

dcast(melt(lst), L1 ~ Var1, fill = 0)
#   L1 0 1 2
# 1  1 3 0 0
# 2  2 1 3 0
# 3  3 0 4 1
```